# Why is this not cast safe?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following utility class:

```
public class MyUtils{

    public static <T> List<? extends T> getList(Class<T> clazz){
        //returning some list
    }
}
```

And a class that uses the method:

```
public class MyClass<T>{

    public static List<MyClass<?>> values(){
        return (List<MyClass<?>>) MyUtils.getList(MyClass.class); //Warning, unchecked cast.
    }
}
```

It's not clear why this isn't cast safe? The result of the method cannot be assigned to a variable like this:

```
List<MyClass<? extends Integer>> lst = MyClass.values(); //compile-error
```

The only way we can assign the result of the method is this:

```
List<MyClass<?>> dsss = MyClass.values();
```

So, what kind of runtime-error may such a cast lead to?

Comment: `MyClass.getList` should be `MyClass.values`, right?

Comment: @CoronA Excatly, I'll fix that in a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getList()` returns a list of an **unknown** type. And you're casting it to a `List<MyClass<?>>`. How could it be safe?

Suppose the returned list is a `List<MyFirstSubClassOfMyClass>`. After you've casted it to `List<MyClass<?>>`, you'll be able to add an instance of MyClass to the list, although the list is supposed to only contain instances of `MyFirstSubClassOfMyClass`.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the cast safety enterily depends on the implementation of `getList(Class<T> clazz)`. I mean if it's implemented as follows `public static <T> List<? extends T> getList(Class<T> clazz){ List<T> lst = new ArrayList<>(); //etc return lst;}` the warning can be suppresed safely, right?

Comment: If that's the implementation, you can suppress the warning, and you won't have a problem at runtime. But that defeats the point of using type-safe generic types. If your method is supposed to always return a List<T>, the its return type should be List<T>, not List<? extends T>.

Comment: If it always returned `List<T>`, the cast `(List<MyClass<?>>) MyUtils.getList(MyClass.class)` would produce compile-error `Cannot cast from List<MyClass> to List<MyClass<?>>`. That's why I made it `List<? extends T>`. Maybe there's another way to deal with such things... I just don't know.

Comment: There's no way to make such a method safe, AFAIK: by passing MyClass.class as argument, you can't specify the generic type of the MyClass instances that are in the list. You'd need something like Jackson's TypeReference: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html